# checking for template class instantiations

Tags: c++

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <type_traits>

template <class C>
struct tmpl
{
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
  std::cout << std::is_class<tmpl<int> >::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_class<tmpl<char> >::value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
1
1
```

But I'd like the compiler to figure out that the template classes `tmpl<int>` and `tmpl<char>` have not yet been instantiated and output `0`. Is it possible? Have I actually instantiated the class template `tmpl` in my example?

Comment: "I'd like the compiler to figure out that `tmpl<int>` ... do not exist" - but they *do* exist, `tmpl<T>` exists for every T!

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm not a template wizard. Reworded.

Comment: Do you mean check for specialisation?

Comment: No, I mean to check for explicit or implicit instantiations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not that way. `is_class` check if it class(not enum for example). If you will break `tmpl` instatioation with SFINAE, you will get compile error.

For example this way:

```
template <>
struct tmpl<int>{ char off[-1];};
```

Answer (score 2):

By naming the type you have instantiated it.  As soon as you refer to `tmpl<SomeTypeNamedFoo>` the compiler will auto-instantiate on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to determine if template-instantiation for particular type has happened or not. Let the compiler do it!

As soon as you make `Temp<T>`, the instantiation has occurred. Even it doesn't occur at this moment, it might have occurred in another translation unit. How are you going to figure out that, and what would you do if instantiation has occurred (or not) in another translation unit? The sequence of instantiations may also be different between different builds of the project.

Comment: While I appreciate the interesting question you posted. But I don't find usefulness of it. And to your question: function-level compilation or link may cause disturbance.

Comment: The purpose was to check whether a pointer or a reference refers to an object, whose class is wrapped in some class wrapper `tmpl<C>`. If yes, then a new wrapper is instantiated using some static variables of `tmpl<C>`. If not, then I cannot instantiate a new wrapper, as the static variables are all zero.